# CCXT / python - custom requests?

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, trading, ccxt

Is there any possibility of making custom GET or POST request with the CCXT API? I can't find some of them in the API requests list,
for example, `GET /api/account/v3/asset-valuation` or `POST /api/margin/v3/accounts/btc-usdt/leverage{"leverage":"10"}` or `GET /api/account/v3/sub-account`

Or maybe there's some way of extracting CCXT auth headers to make a request with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is documented in the CCXT Manual:

- https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/Manual#implicit-api-methods

You can call any API endpoint and send any params as described in the CCXT Manual:

```
import ccxt
exchange = ccxt.okex({
    'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    'secret': 'YOUR_SECRET',
    'password': 'YOUR_API_KEY_PASSWORD',
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})

print(exchange.account_get_asset_valuation({}))  # add params if needed

sub_account_params = {'sub-account': 'YOUR_SUB_ACCOUNT_HERE'}
print(exchange.account_get_sub_account(sub_account_params))

leverage_params = {'instrument_id': 'BTC-USDT', 'leverage': YOUR_LEVERAGE_HERE}
print(exchange.margin_post_accounts_instrument_id_leverage(leverage_params))
```

> Or maybe there's some way of extracting CCXT auth headers to make a request with?

No need for that, CCXT allows you to call any endpoint as you like.